# Send image picker file to the backend

Tags: flutter, dart, backend, laravel-9

So I have this code that picks the image

```
Container(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        result = await FilePicker.platform
                                            .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
                                        if (result == null) {
                                          print("No file selected");
                                        } else {
                                          setState(() {
                                            result?.files.forEach((element) {
                                              attachmentController.text =
                                                  element.name;
                                                
                                              statusController.text = "pending";
                                            });
                                          });
                                          result?.files.forEach((element) {
                                            print(element.name);
                                          });
                                        }
                                      },
```

and I wanted to send this image to the backend of laravel but first, I have an attachment controller that saves the element.name but turns out it's just a name. May I please know how to save the image in the controller and if any links to show how to save that in the laravel backend please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are only picking images i will suggest you to use the *image_picker* package.

In your widget file :

```
File? image;

...
image= await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState({});
```

You can use Image.file, widget factory method to show the image.

In your Api file :

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
...
var response = await http.post('example.com/api',
  body: {
   'image': base64Encode(await imageFile.readAsBytes()),
   },
);
```

Depending on your Laravel you handle the request, decode it from base64 and save it to a folder.